# Jupyter notebook doesn't execute

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am following [yhat's tutorial on predictive analytics](http://blog.yhat.com/posts/predicting-customer-churn-with-sklearn.html), but I ran into some trouble when I reached the cross-validation step. Whenever I try to execute these two pieces of code, Jupyter is stuck in the execution step. Here are the problematic inputs:
Input 1

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold

def run_cv(X,y,clf_class,**kwargs):
    # Construct a kfolds object
    kf = KFold(len(y),n_folds=5,shuffle=True)
    y_pred = y.copy()

    # Iterate through folds
    for train_index, test_index in kf:
        X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
        y_train = y[train_index]
        # Initialize a classifier with key word arguments
        clf = clf_class(**kwargs)
        clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
        y_pred[test_index] = clf.predict(X_test)
    return y_pred
```

In the next input I actually try and compare three algorithms - Input 2:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier as RF
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier as KNN

def accuracy(y_true,y_pred):
    # NumPy interprets True and False as 1. and 0.
    return np.mean(y_true == y_pred)

print "Support vector machines:"
print "%.3f" % accuracy(y, run_cv(X,y,SVC))
print "Random forest:"
print "%.3f" % accuracy(y, run_cv(X,y,RF))
print "K-nearest-neighbors:"
print "%.3f" % accuracy(y, run_cv(X,y,KNN))
```

Is there something wrong with my code or is this a Jupyter issue?

Comment: SVM takes a heck lot of time... whats your data shape?

Comment: And it uses rbf kernel by default, I avoid using SVM with kernel because of this only, try using a linear SVC.

Comment: I am not sure I know what you mean by data shape. However, I can tell you that my training set is about 54k rows with 6 features. Furthermore, how long time can it take? Are we talking several minutes?

Comment: Yup, I'm sure its the SVM, 54k and with a 5 fold cross validation aand with rbf kernel is gonna take time. And I won't recommend you to use linear kernel here then as your features are quite less.

Comment: How long are we talking?

Comment: Depends on your machine.... might take like 1 hour. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just created a dataset of around 54k rows and 3 features and run the same yhat tutorial you have. Took around 30 secs to run, on a 2016 macbook pro.

Don't think there is anything wrong with your code, it just takes a while to run.

To test it, you could limit the size of your dataset and do a test run. If that works, then you know it just takes a while to run.

For example start with just the first 200 samples of your data. Run:

```
X = X[:200]
y = y[:200]
```

before you run the cross validation to limit the data.

Comment: Thanks for this. Now if I want to use the model I just built to actually predict probabilities WITHOUT yhat's software. How would I go about doing this? Quick disclaimer, I am brand new to machine learning. Would really appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: So the `clf.predict` is doing the actual prediction. So you are already, in your notebook, predicting something. If you have no idea what you are doing still, I would check out some more general scikit-learn turorials. Choose one of the three models you use that performs the best, and find a good tutorial that uses scikit-learn and just that model.

Comment: OR check out the cool new tech documentation from SO. There's a RandomForestClassifier example: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/scikit-learn/2468/classification/8146/randomforestclassifier#t=20160722204615349729